# MVC routing when URL path is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 routes defined in my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{customerId}")]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerOrders(string customerId)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{customerId}/{orderId}")]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerOrder(string customerId, string orderId)
    {
    }
```

Now, if someone passes in a url like http://myApp/api/Orders//6d1a30ed-045b-4ea3-845e-e1b7ebd8f6a5 (so customerId is null); it ends up matching on the first route (with `orderId` in the `customerId` parameter); but I really want it to go to the 2nd.  How can I make it so it lands on the 2nd with a null value in `customerId`?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. 
/api/orders suggests that you are using web api. i am guessing that you want to communicate this url to users to browse to however. I would suggest you remove the api in the url.

```
[Route("{customerId}")]
```

should be

```
[Route("api/Orders/{customerId}")]
```

And the other

```
[Route("api/Order/{customerId}/{orderId}")]
```